# How to get Gmail contacts photo

Tags: php, google-contacts-api

Hi I have an application to list out all the Gmail contacts with their details after login and I have written like

```
$xmlresponse = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full?oauth_token=' . $accesstoken . '&max-results=100');
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlresponse);
$xml->registerXPathNamespace('gd', 'http://schemas.google.com/g/2014');
```

And using this Iam getting `hrefs` array but if I given them in `src` attribute in img tag,they are not displaying images.But Iam getting name and email correctly

Comment: Could you share us sample xml response?